# Generate RSA Keypair in the KeyStore on API level 21

Tags: android

So the `KeyGenParameterSpec` was introduced in API level 23 so on lower API levels I need to use the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec`. However, when setting the type I get an error with Android Studio saying the type must be (in this case) `KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA`. However that constant was introduced in API level 23 so it wont work for API level 22 for example!

I've tried just replacing it with the constant value which is `"RSA"` but it wont accept it.

Any idea how I get around this?

```
KeypairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
    .setKeyType("RSA")
    .build();
```

So in the above simplified example, I set the keytype to "RSA" but Android Studio wont compile and forces me to use `KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA` which again, is only available in API level 23 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from:

[Android RSA Keypair Generation - Should I use Standard Java/Bouncy Castle/Spongy Castle/JSch/Other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962825/android-rsa-keypair-generation-should-i-use-standard-java-bouncy-castle-spongy)

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are seeing are the inspection rules output. I also got the same inspection error but build is working fine and running as expected.

If you want to remove the inspection error, you can edit the inspection rules. However this is not required.